# Display the value on to the label below the applicant pending

Tags: php, html

[image]

I have to pull out the value from the database table call `count.php` which I already got the value 49. The problem is how to insert into the html

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "hopeplace";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_APPLICANT FROM applicant";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["TOTAL_APPLICANT"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

code for the container for the applicant pending

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <div class="icon-big icon-danger text-center">
                <i class="ti-user"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <div class="numbers">
                <p>Applicant Pending</p>
                <p>*this is the place where value need to be put*</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <hr />

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can write html tag inside php file. Combine both the code and save as .php file. Then use `<p><?php echo $total;?></p>` like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign value to one variable and echo that variable inside html

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "hopeplace";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$count = 0;
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_APPLICANT FROM applicant";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $count = $row["TOTAL_APPLICANT"] ;
   }
} 
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

code for the container for the applicant pending will be like

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <div class="icon-big icon-danger text-center">
        <i class="ti-user"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <div class="numbers">
        <p>Applicant Pending</p>
        <p>
          <?php echo $count; ?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

save both html & php in same file or ensure that your html code is saved as a `.php` file. So, your script will be - `<p><?php echo $total; ?></p>` or `<p><?= $total ?></p>`